# Adding objects from array to dictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, dictionary

I am getting rows from a SQLite DB and trying to insert them into a dictionary. Except I keep getting errors! I get the error "Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'const id *' is disallowed with ARC" Which I know means that I cant use a pointer when I am adding objects to my dictionary. So how do I go about fixing it so I can add those arrays to a dictionary?

```
    NSArray *keyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init ];
    NSArray *valueArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc ] init ];
    NSDictionary* dic;
    NSInteger dataCount = sqlite3_data_count(statement);
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        @try {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataCount; i ++)
            {
                NSString* key = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i)];  
                NSString *value = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i)];

                if ([value length] == 0)
                {
                    value = @"";
                }

                keyArray = [keyArray arrayByAddingObject:key];
                valueArray = [valueArray arrayByAddingObject:value];

            }

        }
        @catch (NSException *ex)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@,%@", [ex name], [ex reason]);
        }

        dic= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:valueArray forKeys:keyArray count:[keyArray count]];
```

Comment: Why not use NSMutableArrays? And where exactly is your error?

Comment: On what line are you getting the error

Comment: A `0` length string is already `@""` and there is no need to check the value. If you are checking for `NULL` then you need to check the value of `sqlite3_column_text` because `stringWithUTF8String:` will crash on `NULL` values.

Answer (score 5):

The `dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:` takes C-style arrays, not `NSArray` objects. The `dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:` may do the trick, but you may be better off constructing a mutable dictionary as you go, bypassing `NSArray`s entirely.

```
NSDictionary* dic;
NSMutableDictionary *tmp = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (int i = 0; i < dataCount; i ++)
{
    NSString* key = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i)];  
    NSString *value = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i)];
    [tmp setObject:value forKey:key];
}
dict = tmp;
```

Comment: `dictionaryWithObjects:<#(NSArray *)#> forKeys:<#(NSArray *)#>` takes NSArrays, would that help?

Comment: @OscarHernandez Thank you very much for bringing this up, I updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Since your answer is correct lets nitpick at it! Remove the `[value length]` check as it is unnecessary. See my comment above.

Comment: @Joe You're right, the value is not `nil` there, because a DB null would have crashed the line above it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[dicBodyPost setValue:arrContactAddress forKey:@"contactAddress"];